# Socket.io connection event not fired on server

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I am trying to build a command-line chat room using Node.js and Socket.io.

This is my server-side code so far, I have tried this with both http initialisations (with express, like on the official website's tutorial, and without it):

```
#app = require('express')()
#http = require('http').Server(app)
http = require('http').createServer()
io = require('socket.io')(http)


io.sockets.on 'connect', (socket) ->
  console.log 'a user connected'


http.listen 3000, () ->
  console.log 'listening on *:3000'
```

I start this with `nodejs server.js`, the "Listening on" is showing up.

If I run `lsof -i tcp:3000`, the server.js process shows up.

However, when I start this client-side code:

```
socket = require('socket.io-client')('localhost:3000', {})

socket.on 'connect', (socket) ->
  console.log "Connected"
```

No luck... When I run nodejs client.js, neither "connect" events, from server nor client, are fired!

My questions are :
- What am I doing wrong? 
- Is it necessary to start a HTTP server to use it? Sockets are on the transport layer, right? So in theory I don't need a HTTP protocol to trade messages.

Comment: That's Coffeescript...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server to server connection and you're only making a socket.io connection (not also setting it up for regular HTTP connections), then this code shows the simple way for just a socket.io connection:

**Listening socket.io-only server**

```
// Load the library and initialize a server on port 3000
// This will create an underlying HTTP server, start it and bind socket.io to it
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

// listen for incoming client connections and log connect and disconnect events
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("socket.io connect: ", socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("socket.io disconnect: ", socket.id);
    });
});
```

**Node.js socket.io client - connects to another socket.io server**

```
// load the client-side library
const io = require('socket.io-client');
// connect to a server and port
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

// listen for successful connection to the server
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("socket.io connection: ", socket.id);
});
```

This code works on my computer.  I can run two separate node.js apps on the same host and they can talk to one another and both see the connect and disconnect events.

**Some Explaining**

The socket.io protocol is initiated by making an HTTP connection to an HTTP server.  So, anytime you have a socket.io connection, there is an HTTP server listening somewhere.  That HTTP connection is initially sent with some special headers that indicate to the server that this is a request to "upgrade" to the webSocket protocol and some additional security info is included.

This is [pretty great reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) on how a webSocket connection is initially established.  It will show you step by step what happens.

Once both sides agree on the "upgrade" in protocol, then the protocol is switched to webSocket (socket.io is then an additional protocol layer on top of the base webSocket protocol, but the connection is all established at the HTTP/webSocket level).  Once the upgrade is agreed upon, the exact same TCP connection that was originally the incoming HTTP connection is repurposed and becomes the webSocket/socket.io connection.

With the socket.io server-side library, you can either create the HTTP server yourself and then pass that to socket.io or you can have socket.io just create one for you.  If you're only using socket.io on this server and not also sharing using http server for regular http requests, then you can go either way.  The minimal code example above, just lets socket.io create the http server for you transparently and then socket.io binds to it.  If you are also fielding regular web requests from the http server, then you would typically create the http server first and then pass it to socket.io so socket.io could bind to the http server you already have.

Then, keep in mind that socket.io is using the webSocket transport.  It's just some additional packet structure on top of the webSocket transport.  It would akin to agreeing to send JSON across an HTTP connection.  HTTP is the host transport and underlying data format.  Both sides then agree to format some data in JSON format and send it across HTTP.  The socket.io message format sits on top of webSocket in that way.

**Your Questions**

> Is it necessary to start a HTTP server to use it?

Yes, an HTTP server must exist somewhere because all socket.io connections start with an HTTP request to an HTTP server.

> Sockets are on the transport layer, right?

The initial connection protocol stack works like this:

```
TCP <- HTTP protocol
```

Then, after the protocol upgrade:

```
TCP <- webSocket <- socket.io
```

So after the protocol upgrade from HTTP to the webSocket transport, you then have socket.io packet format sitting on top of the webSocket format sitting on top of TCP.

> So in theory I don't need a HTTP protocol to trade messages.

No, that is not correct.  All connections are initially established with HTTP.  Once the upgrade happens to the webSocket transport, HTTP is no longer used.

Comment: @Matheus208 - Did this answer your question?  If so, please check the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate to the community that your question has now been answered and to also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.  If this did not answer your question, then please comment on what it is still missing so the answer can be edited to complete it.